# Switch statement using a String type

Tags: android

I'm trying to switch a string type value which I have made static.  However I can't figure out how to put this into a switch statement I was previously using an 'if else' statement but due to the number of items I want to switch this doesn't work.

For the if else I was using `

```
if (item.ActivityFeedType.equals("Comment"))
```

for switch I;m trying to use

```
case (item.ActivityFeedType.equals("Comment")):
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you use a Java version below 7, is impossible to switch a String

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. `switch` for Strings exists, but it's only available starting from Java 7. The syntax actually is just as with an `Integer` switch:

   ```
   String test = "test";
   switch (test) { 
       case "testt": 
           System.out.println("Wrong"); 
           break; 
       case "test": 
           System.out.println("Got it"); 
           break; 
   }
   ```
2. There is no situation that a switch can handle, but a simple if-else could not. A switch simply is more convenient.
3. I'd recommend selecting lower-case starting letters for a Class' attributes.

Comment: I think its probably better for me to use an if else but on the last else I'm getting an error '; expected'

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a syntax error. It does not mean if-else does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Thouhg if you are working with Java 1.7,
**Java's `switch-case` allows only constant variable in `case`.**

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to switch strings below jdk 7.

You should get an error message similiar to:

> Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7.
>   Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Answer (score 1):

The java 6 compiler does not allow you to use `switch` with reference types (`String`, `Object`, etc.). You can only do this with the following value types - `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int`. If you use a higher version of the JVM, you can do a `switch` over `String` values too.

Now to your question. The android build tools use JVM 6 so you cannot use the new `switch` abilities.

Answer (score 1):

**Note : Below java 7 it is not possible to use strings in switch.**

if you are using java 7 or above you can use as below

```
String item="mango";

switch(item){
case "mango" :
      System.out.println("this is mango");
 break;
 ............
 ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using java version 7+

```
switch(item.ActivityFeedType){
case "Comment":
//do stuff
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Java 1.7 in build gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```